# Creating table/columns combinations using SQL Query or Laravel SQL Query Builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, combinations, sku

I have an existing scheme for products variations.

I want to create a combination of each production time, quantities and variation options.

I will create a selection form by accessing the quantities, production times, variation and variation options from the product.

**table_groups**

```
+------------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| 1  | rug   |
+----+-------+
```

**table_days**

```
+----+----------+------+
| id | group_id | day  |
+----+----------+------+
| 1  | 1        | 1    |
| 2  | 1        | 2    |
| 3  | 1        | 3    |
+----+----------+------+
```

**table_quantities**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | group_id | quantity  |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | 100       |
| 2  | 1        | 200       |
| 3  | 1        | 300       |
| 4  | 1        | 400       |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

**table_attributes**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | group_id | title     |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | Color     |
| 2  | 1        | Size      |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

**table_attribute_values**

```
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
| id | group_id | attribute_id | title  |
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
| 1  | 1        | 1            | Red    |
| 2  | 1        | 1            | Yellow |
| 3  | 1        | 1            | Black  |
| 4  | 1        | 2            | Small  |
| 5  | 1        | 2            | Medium |
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
```

I prepared an example schema. However, I am not getting the result I want.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2168b/3/0)**

**This much I did do:**

```sql
SELECT
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT days_group) as days_list,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quantities_group SEPARATOR ',') as quantities_list,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT attribute_values_group SEPARATOR ',') as attribute_values_list
FROM
    table_groups
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT days.day, days.group_id,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(days.day) as days_group
            FROM table_days days GROUP BY days.id
        ) joindays ON joindays.group_id = table_groups.id

    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT quantities.quantity, quantities.group_id,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(quantities.quantity) as quantities_group
            FROM table_quantities quantities GROUP BY quantities.id
        ) joinquantities ON joinquantities.group_id = table_groups.id

    LEFT JOIN table_attributes attributes ON attributes.group_id = table_groups.id

    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT attribute_id, group_id,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_values.title) as attribute_values_group
            FROM table_attribute_values attribute_values
            GROUP BY attribute_values.attribute_id, attribute_values.id
        ) joinattributevalues ON joinattributevalues.attribute_id = attributes.id

GROUP BY joinattributevalues.attribute_id;
```

**Query Results:**

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| group_id      | days_list | quantities_list | attribute_values_list |
+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| 1             | 1,2,3     | 100,200,300,400 | Red,Yellow,Black      |
| 2             | 1,2,3     | 100,200,300,400 | Small,Medium          |
+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

The correct result I want should be as follows. Can you help with this?

```
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| group_id  | combinations        | price  |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-100-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-100-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-100-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-100-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-100-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-100-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-200-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-200-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-200-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-200-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-200-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-200-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-300-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-300-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-300-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-300-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-300-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-300-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-400-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-400-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-400-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-400-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-400-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 1-400-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-100-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-100-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-100-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-100-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-100-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-100-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-200-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-200-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-200-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-200-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-200-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-200-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-300-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-300-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-300-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-300-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-300-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-300-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-400-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-400-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-400-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-400-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-400-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 2-400-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-100-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-100-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-100-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-100-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-100-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-100-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-200-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-200-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-200-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-200-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-200-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-200-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-300-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-300-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-300-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-300-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-300-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-300-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-400-Red-Small     |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-400-Red-Medium    |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-400-Yellow-Small  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-400-Yellow-Medium |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-400-Black-Small   |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3-400-Black-Medium  |        |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+
```

**Note:** There is no limit for the number of groups, attributes, and attributes values. The example result might be something like this:

```
Attributes:

+-------+------+-------+--------+
| Color | Size | Model | Gender |
+-------+------+-------+--------+

Combinations:

+------------------------------+
| 1-100-Red-Small-Model 1-Male |
+------------------------------+
| 1-100-Red-Small-Model 2-Male |
+------------------------------+
```

It is not necessary to do it with SQL query. We can also do this with the Laravel Query Builder method.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**[Check the sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2168b/3/0)**

Comment: Is MySQL 5.6 a requirement, or do you have access to MySQL 8.0 and/or other DBs?

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee My first choice is mysql 5.7 but if necessary I will using it in mysql 8. It can also be done with Laravel query builder methods. I haven't slept for a many days. It would be a luxury for me to choose the mysql version:)

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee it will be useful to examine this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/64851724/6320082

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. Will not function in mysql 5.7 because recursive CTEs weren't included until later, but this will allow you to have a variable number of attributes and attribute_values per group_id. The fiddle is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xpGaXxcmuFUYazSLC84r3h/4#).

```sql
with recursive allAtts as (
  /* Get our attribute list, and format it if we want; concat(a.title, ':', v.title) looks quite nice */
  SELECT 
    att.group_id,
    att.id,
    CONCAT(v.title) as attDesc,
    dense_rank() over (partition by att.group_id order by att.id) as attRank
FROM table_attributes att 
INNER JOIN table_attribute_values v 
    ON v.group_id = att.group_id 
    AND v.attribute_id = att.id 
 ),
 cte as (
 /* Recursively build our attribute list, assuming ranks are sequential and we properly linked our group_ids */
    select group_id, id, attDesc, attRank from allAtts WHERE attRank = 1
   
         union all 
   
    select 
        allAtts.group_id, 
        allAtts.id, 
        concat_ws('-', cte.attDesc, allAtts.attDesc) as attDesc,
        allAtts.attRank
   from cte 
   join allAtts ON allAtts.attRank = cte.attRank +1
      AND cte.group_id = allAtts.group_id
)
   
/* Our actual select statement, which RIGHT JOINs against the table_groups 
   so we don't lose entries w/o attributes */   
select 
    grp.id,
    concat_ws('-', d.day, qty.quantity, cte.attDesc) as combinations
from cte 
inner join (select group_id, max(attRank) as attID
            from cte
            group by group_id) m on cte.group_id = m.group_id and m.attID = cte.attrank
RIGHT JOIN table_groups grp ON grp.id = cte.group_id 
LEFT JOIN table_days d on grp.id = d.group_id
LEFT JOIN table_quantities qty on grp.id = qty.group_id;
```

Comment: thank you very much! i will now upgrade the mysql version. and then i'll test it right away.

Comment: i owe you a lot. you are awesome!